# Python 3 constructor keeps non-static value accross instances

Tags: python, syntax, constructor, python-3.6

These days I don't tend to find myself surprised with Python unless I mess around with syntax corner-cases however, this one left me quite speechless. Apologies if the question title is not great.

```
class foo(object):

    def __init__(self, l=[]):
        self.l = l

    def get_l(self):
        return self.l

    @staticmethod
    def make_foo(a):
        f = foo()
        f.l.append(a)
        return f

f1 = foo.make_foo(1)
f2 = foo.make_foo(2)
print(f1.l)
print(f2.l)
```

Does this look obvious to you? It did to me. You should see on the output:

```
[1]
[2]
```

Actually you'll see (with 3.6.2) at least:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

However, you'll get the expected result if you do `f = foo([])` in `make_foo`. Now, why that's the case I don't understand. Can anyone clarify why we get this unexpected result and why passing explicitly the empty list, changes what we get?

Comment: Explanation and possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument  To be clear, this behavior has nothing to do with classes or constructors. You can find the same behavior using a trivial function `def bar(a=[]): a.append(1)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ you're right. It's about mutable default values. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, the same behavior occurs with mutable or immutable objects, but it only makes a difference if the object is mutable